# cassandraOperations.select ignore null values

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I am trying to get `User` using `cassandraOperations.select(s, User.class)` but I am getting below error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set boolean field com.rogs.cassandra.User.userStatus to null value
```

Error is correct as I have `null` values for `userStatus` of some users in Cassandra DB, is there anyway to ignore the `null` while getting results with `cassandraOperations`.

My User class is here.

```
@Table
public class User{
    @PrimaryKey
    private String userId;
    private String userName;
    private String userDept;
    private boolean userStatus;
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exception you are getting is `IllegalArgumentException` and not `NullPointerException`. Here you are trying to set null object in boolean field (true/false). You should change the boolean type to Wrapper type like below.

```
 private Boolean userStatus;
```